# How to add value dynamically in table cell using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

For example I have an table filled with values

```
-----------------------------------------
S.No   |   Name      |       Address
-----------------------------------------
       |  Dinesh     |       Salem
-----------------------------------------
       |  Senthil    |       Chennai
-----------------------------------------
       |  Sundar     |       Namakkal
-----------------------------------------
```

Actually I need to fill `serial no` to each row dynamically using jQuery.

```
var i = 1;
$('#tbl td').each(function() {
    $(this).append(i);
    i++;
});
```

I need the output should be:

```
-----------------------------------------
S.No    |   Name      |       Address
-----------------------------------------
   1    |  Dinesh     |       Salem
-----------------------------------------
   2    |  Senthil    |       Chennai
-----------------------------------------
   3    |  Sundar     |       Namakkal
-----------------------------------------
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanna replace first td , you can use `:first-child`

Try like this

```
var i=1;
$('#tbl td:first-child').each(function() {
    $(this).html(i);
    i++;
});
```